# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.web.util.ExpressionEvaluationUtils

Tags: spring

I am upgrading my project from WAS 8 to WAS 9, since WAS 9 needs jdk 8 and spring 4 is compatible with jdk8. So I am changing my spring old jar to spring 4 jar. After changing I am getting the ExpressionEvaluationUtils exception.

I know it is removed in spring 4. In the jsp pages I am not getting an error. After deploying I am getting this above exception:

> at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892) Caused
>   by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.springframework.web.util.ExpressionEvaluationUtils    at
>   org.springframework.security.taglibs.authz.AuthorizeTag.doStartTag(AuthorizeTag.java:82)

Comment: You cannot just upgrade only Spring, you will also need to upgrade the other libraries like Spring Security (which is the one complaining here).

Comment: See if http://java.candidjava.com/tutorial/List-of-jar-for-spring-MVC-example.htm may help you.

Comment: thank you . i will try to upgrade my spring security jars also.